# specify variable array index for liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

My liquid code is

```
{% assign _product_id = product.id %}
  {% assign _product_tag = product.collections[0].title}
  {% assign _product_name = product.title %}

  {{_product_tag}}
  {% assign pagla_array = collections[_product_tag].products %}

  {{ pagla_array.first.title }}
```

Here last line showing nothing. if I use a static index for assigning `pagla_array` like {% assign pagla_array = `collections['Beans'].products %}` then it show value. What wrong did I make here?

Comment: Typo missing % at close element: `{% assign _product_tag = product.collections[0].title}` should `{% assign _product_tag = product.collections[0].title %}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

> {% assign _product_tag = product.collections[0].title}

Is not closed correctly. It should end with `%}`

In addition you should use handles for the collections, not title.

So it should become:

```
{% assign _product_tag = product.collections[0].handle %}
....
{% assign pagla_array = collections[_product_tag].products %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. Now can you explain what actually happens with handle?

Comment: Handle returns a handlized title, so that all special characters are escaped properly. So for example if you have a collection called "Foo Bar", the handle version is `foo-bar`. That's why you have to get collections with handles or you get something like `collections[Foo Bar]` which is an invalid syntax.

Comment: thank you very much. I am new in shopify and never used liquid. This was the first time writing liquid. Thanks again for helping me.